# How to password protect WordPress blog using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, xampp, password-protection

This question is with respect to local host on my PC which is shared on the local network. I want selected people to access the website using .htaccess method or something similar. I used the following code for [.htacces/.htpasswd](http://www.4webhelp.net/tutorials/misc/htaccess.php) method

```
// .htaccess file
AuthName "Realm name"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user 


// .htpasswd file
frances:WrU808BHQai36
```

This method is suppose to work but it is not working for me. I once got the dialog box asking for username and password but never again? Does this method work on localhost. Note: my wordpress blog is sitting in C:\blog folder which is outside XAMPP HTDOC folder.

Comment: If you got it once, and typed in the correct password, my guess would be you are validated. Your browser might even be saving the password, but even if not, you are likely still authenticated. Does it prompt again if you clear your cache/cookies/etc?

Comment: If the username/password is being used on subsequent visits, it'd show in the webserver's access logs, and viewing the http headers would show the auth header as well.

Comment: I looked up stored passwords in FireFox, it wasn't there. I just now cleared all cookies for localhost but that dialog still does not pop up.

Comment: @ktash, you suggestion worked. After clearing all cookies, the dialog shows up. I am not able to login though and if enter an incorrect password, the dialog never pops up again. Someone can help on that. You may want to write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems that I were having. One was wrong .htaccess file, the other was wrong password encryption. After fixing this everything worked fine. Note: I visit a number of site and their encryption did not work for me.

```
// 1. note the /blog/ folder needs to be there. 
// Without it, the dialog box does not pop again

AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /blog/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

For correct encryption for XAMPP 1.7.6, the password generated by [this site](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) worked for me but for many other it did not.

Some provided even complete htaccess and htpasswd rewrite [like this one](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/) but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser will store your authentication on entering in your information so you only will need to authenticate once. To fix this, clear your cache/cookies and you should get prompted for a password again.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to use 
[WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/)